# The structure of Banach manifolds in symplectic geometry

Tags: soft-question, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, banach-manifold

Let $M$ be a symplectic manifold, and let $L_0$ and $L_1$ be Lagrangian submanifolds which transverse to each other. In Floer theory, we need to consider a Banach manifold $\mathcal B$ of maps $u:\mathbb R \times [0,1] \to M$ which are locally $W^{1,p}$, which converge in some sense on the strip ends, and which also satisfies the boundary conditions that $u(\mathbb R\times \{0\} \subset L_0, ~ u(\mathbb R\times\{1\} \subset L_1$. (Actually, the definition of $\mathcal B$ varies from different contexts.) How can we see the structure of Banach manifold on $\mathcal B$?

1. We usually use the exponential map (with respect to some metric on $M$) to define the local chart map $\xi \mapsto \exp_u\xi$ for an infinite-dimensional manifold consisting of mappings. However, in the above case, the nearby map $\exp_u\xi$ may fail to satisfy the boundary condition, unless we further assume $L_0, L_1$ are totally geodesic with respect to this metric. So, in general, does there exist a metric so that given Lagrangians are totally geodesic? If not, what is an alternative way to find the local charts of $\mathcal B$?
2. (The following may not be a serious question) In general I noticed that people in symplectic geometry often claim something is a Banach manifold without satisfactory explanations. Especially when I consider Banach manifolds of mappings satisfying some additional boundary conditions or asymptotic conditions, I feel very worry about the rigorousness of checking the structure of Banach manifolds. The above question is only one example of my worry. I was wondering if it is good for a graduate to worry this stuff? Perhaps it could be good to just admit it, or not?

Comment: For (1), the existence of such metric (with better properties) is proved by Frauenfelder (see Lemma 4.3.3 of the book ``J-holomorphic curves and symplectic topology'', or Frauenfelder's paper).